# Trying to pickle a neural network, but getting error I don't understand

Tags: python, pickle

I have a neural network that predicts heart disease, which works with about a 95% confidence. I'm trying to pickle the model, but I get the following error I don't understand, even after googling it: "TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects." Does this mean I can't pickle a model that relies on a read csv file? How can I fix this so I can pickle the model?

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(nn, open("heart_disease.pkl", "wb"))
```